# open local gsheet in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a google drive link on my local hard disk.

I don't always have internet connection.

Normally I use an export link from gsheet to download an sheet into my pandas dataframe, like so:

```
link = link.replace(r"edit?usp=sharing", "export?format=xlsx")
in_df = read_excel(link, engine='openpyxl')
```

When I don't have an internet connection, I'd like to use my local copy instead. It is saved in `G:\mystuff\sheet.gsheet`.

Is there any way in python pandas, to open that sheet from the local copy? The question is specifically about how to open `.gsheet` format files that are on a local drive, as I don't have the google api "export" function locally and it is not `.xlsx`.